# Visual Studio Project Migration

Tags: visual-studio-2005, migration, projects

Is there a way where I can transfer a ASP.Net application completely to a new system? I have copied the project directory before and it usually works, but I have issues with "References".

I'm trying to take over a project from a person and he gave me all the files ( including the .sln files ), but I've got a bunch of reference errors ( like Microsoft.Data is not defined etc )

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry to bother if this question has been asked before by somebody.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends somewhat on the particular references, but start by right-clicking on "References", select "Add Reference". In the dialog that appears, start with the ".NET" tab and see if you can find them in that list.

If the references you need are missing, you may have to obtain third-party software. For example, if the project uses log4net, you'll have to download that. Once you have the DLL locally, add it by following the same steps; except instead of using the .NET tab, click "Browse" and find the DLL where you installed it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that if the references are made to installed files on the old machine that these files exist on the new machine. You could copy the references dlls to a tools folder and then reference form there and that way the machine would build in a new environment easily